# ggplot using filter for one data

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data contains 29 different ID with each ID containing sub ID with their measurement value, upper bound value and lower bound value, time stamp.

I am trying to create a ggplot with points, where I could filter for one ID and plot their sub ID with measurement value, lower bound and upperbound value.

I am using the below, code, helped by satckoverflow, but anyone could how I could incorporate the filter function here.

My data looks like this. for sample

```
data<- data.frame(c(ST_10,ST_11,ST_10,ST_10,ST_11,ST_10) , c(M1,M3,M2,M5,M7,M9), c(0.3,0.5,1.98,198),c(0.2,0.4,1.98,199),c(0.1,0.3,1.0,190) )
```

this is just a sample, and I am using the below code.

```
ggplot(data)+
  geom_jitter(aes(x=Day.ID., y=Measurement.Value, col=as.factor(Day.ID.)))+
  geom_line(aes(x=Day.ID., y=LSL.ID), colour='orange')+
  geom_line(aes(x=Day.ID., y=USL.ID), colour='orange')+
  facet_wrap(~DESC)
```

according to the code, data is my data name, day is the timestamp, LSL is lower bound, USL is upperbound, and Desc is the  sub ID

Comment: Your question is not clear. If I understand correctly, you want to plot the upper and lower bounds for ever single ID individually? Also can you correct your code, what is `ST_10,ST_11` etc, character vector? Also your numeric vectors have different length compared to the other character vectors. Also name your dataframe variables, currently you refer to `LSL.ID` but we have no clue which varaible it is.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()`. See more [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)